# Having both an anchor and paragraph inline with an image

Tags: html, css

Here's what I have so far:http://jsfiddle.net/hLbyy/4/ using `margin` property.

I have looked at various page sources (such as [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/floating-inline-images-with-multiple-paragraphswhere) where the user's avatar is inline with their details, yet this appears to be within a paragraph rather than a list item.) but I was unable to find the line of CSS that achieved this.

Any help towards achieving this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, probably due to my poor phrasing, it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Having the anchor above the paragraph, and still inline with the image, is what I was after. (like this http://jsfiddle.net/hLbyy/16/ but the paragraph higher up)

Comment: @KryDos has the right idea, then just adjust your margin, [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/hLbyy/23/).

Answer (score 0):

Use "`float: left;`" style for img tag.

Somehow like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/hLbyy/11/).

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for what you want to do is to wrap the link with the image in a div, then style this div as:

```
display: block;
```

And wrap your link and text in another div which should align automatically at the right of your image, if you want to get fancier, you can wrap both divs in a div.

Comment: Display: block will (by default) be 100% width, and is the default disply style of a div.  For what you're talking about, both divs would have to have a width (which would have to combine to < 100%) and they may need to float, depending on the layout of the rest of his site.